# LINQ/From-Select vs ForEach

Tags: c#, linq

I did some searching here and elsewhere but can't find precisely what I'm asking.  I've this code from some example code I'm working through.

```
 public CountryViewModel(Region[] regions)
    {
        _regions = new ReadOnlyCollection<RegionViewModel>(
            (from region in regions
             select new RegionViewModel(region))
            .ToList());
    }
```

I believe the above is equivalent to:

```
  public CountryViewModel(Region[] regions)
    {
        _regions = new ReadOnlyCollection<RegionViewModel>();
        foreach (region in regions)
        {  
            _regions.Add(new RegionViewModel(region)); 
        }
    }
```

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem with the above code that you need help with?

Comment: No.  Im trying to confirm my understanding that the from/select in the first statement will populate _regions with instances of RegionViewModel.  I know I could do that with a foreach statement.  I thought the question was clear as asked.

Answer (score 2):

No, the code snippets aren't equivalent.  The second snippet doesn't compile for multiple different reasons.  You haven't defined `region`, there is no parameterless constructor for `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, and `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` has no `Add` method.  Since the first snippet compiles and successfully creates a `ReadOnlyCollection<RegionViewModel>` it doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: Indeed, ReadOnlyCollection<T> has an Add method since it inherits the ICollection<T> interface but throws an NotSupportedException

Comment: See my above comment.

Comment: @DavidGreen What about the answer wasn't clear?  You asked if the two snippets were equivalent.  They are not, and I explained why they are not.

Comment: true.  I thought my question was clear.  apparently it was't.  I suppose what I coud have asked was, assuming both statements compiled, would they both result in _regions being populated with instances of RegionViewModel

Comment: @DavidGreen If you assumed that both snippets compiled  then your question would be based on a false premise, since the second statement *doesn't* compile.  The runtime behavior of the snippet cannot be discussed because it *has* no runtime behavior, because it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Servy I believe DavidGreen is simply asking a conceptual question based off of two _non-complete_ code snippets. _Assuming_ the other constructors are present in the actual program and barring any minor syntax issues, I think the question is straight forward. See my response for further thoughts.

Comment: @KayoticSully But it's *not* just minor syntax issues.  You can't add items to a **READ ONLY** collection.  This is a major *conceptual* problem with the code.  It makes no sense at all to add items to a *read only* collection.

Comment: @Servy I did miss the _ReadOnlyCollection_ and had assumed it was a normal Collection.  That's what I get for reading quickly and assuming...  If it wasn't for that the code would work, but you are right, ReadOnly is ReadOnly.  Although I think it would have helped a bit to explain that as the reason in the first place. I had completely glazed that detail over in my mind as I am sure OP did which created much of this confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Both of those snippets achieve the same goal (barring minor syntax issues), **conceptually** they will have the same end result.

However, there may be performance differences of which I could not comment on.  I don't have a great working knowledge of C#'s inner workings but I suspect that the LINQ statement would yield better performance.  I could be completely wrong on that assertion though.

**Edit:**
My above statements had assumed a normal Collection and not a ReadOnlyCollection as I had missed that detail.  I retract my statements.  The first code sample is the only one that could work here because that structure is ReadOnly.